# White space on right side of responsive navigation menu - how do I remove it?

Tags: html, css

This is the HTML code for the menu:

```html
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a href="glavna.php" class="active"><img src="../slike/logo.svg" id="logo"></a>
    <a href="glavna.php">Pregled</a>
    <a href="dodaj.php">Unos</a>
    <a href="izmeni.php">Izmena</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

This is the CSS:

```css
body {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll; 
}

.topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: red;
    margin-top: -5px;
    margin-right: 0;
}

#header {
    margin-right: 0;
}
  
.topnav a {
    float:left;
    display: block;
    color: #17161a;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
  
.topnav a.active {
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: 60px;
    padding-left: 0;
    float:left;
    display: block;
    color: #17161a;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 10px;
    justify-content: center;
}
  
  .topnav .icon {
    display: none;
  }

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
    .topnav a.icon {
      float: right;
      display: block;
      margin-right: 20px;
    }
  }
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .topnav.responsive {
        position: relative; 
        padding-bottom: 10px;     
        margin-top: -5px;        
        background-color: green;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .topnav.responsive .icon {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
    }
    .topnav.responsive a {
      float: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: right;
      margin-right: 20px;
    }
  }

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

   body {
       background-color: #ffffff;
       margin-left: -20px;
       border: 0;
       padding: 0;
       font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
       height: 100%;
   }
}
```

There's a white thin border on the right side of the navigation bar that I want to get rid of. I've tried accounting for the margins and padding and such but I can't seem to fix it. The random red and green colors I've been using for differentiating visually. Can someone please help me out?

Edit:

For anyone running into a similar problem, check the width of your scrollbar, that was creating the problem for me:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {

   ::-webkit-scrollbar {
            width: 0px;
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't see a problem, except for the scrollbars. Can you show an image of the problem?

Comment: If you remove this ```overflow-y: scroll;``` under *html, body { }* style, what will happen?

Comment: The line disappeared, thank you. I set the scroller width to 0 and it's working fine now.